# Error when I set compilers! need a little help

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

when I run

> web3.eth.getCompilers()

I found that Solidity is not my geth compiler. I try to set it by

> admin.setSolc("/usr/local/bin/solc")
>   An error that

```
Error:solc:exit status 1
      at web3.js:3119:20
      at web3.js:6023:15
      at web3.js:4995:36
      at <anonymous>:1:2
```

so I try to use solcjs and it worked.
But when i compile with contract,the same ERROR happend.Someone know what's wrong?thx very much.[image: LOG]

Comment: what's which solc
 returns?

Comment: and /usr/local/bin/solc --version ??

Comment: you can try this command :
`admin.setSolc("/usr/bin/solc")`

Answer (score 2):

I think your first error is due to invalid path to `solc`.
You can check if it is really at `/usr/local/bin/solc`:

```
$ whereis solc
solc: /usr/bin/solc
```

You get second error because `geth` (at least versions <=1.5.6) **does not support** `solcjs` as Solidity compiler (see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3015#issuecomment-260713784)).

`geth` tries to run `solc` with arguments which are not supported by `solcjs` (see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/f2da6581ba827a2aab091f764ace8017b26450d8/common/compiler/solidity.go#L36-L40)).

Comment: If you had multiple copies of `solc` on your machine, `whereis solc` would return all of them. Using `which solc` will return just the one that would be executed in the current environment. (So the first occurrence that appears in `$PATH`.)

Comment: thx. solved it. :)